# How to propagate type-class evidence through the method chain

Tags: scala, factory, typeclass, implicit

I have the following skeleton of the `SMap[K]` data structure where I want to have special `Entry[K]` type for the specialized key.
I was following the approach of using the Factory type-class to create the special entries.
And it works just fine when I am creating the Entry directly.
But it fails when I need to create them deep in the method chain.

[Live code](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/dadhi/G2uzgCqXSbiav34bM602iw/68)

```scala
// Some Map skeleton, methods does not matter - just for demonstration of method chain
trait SMap[@specialized(Int) K] {
  def updated(key: K): SMap[K] = EntryFactory.create(key)  
  def +(key: K): SMap[K] = updated(key)
}
object SMap {
  private case object Empty extends SMap[Nothing]
  def empty[K]: SMap[K] = Empty.asInstanceOf[SMap[K]]
}

abstract class Entry[K] extends SMap[K]
case class KEntry[K](key: K, keyHash: Int) extends Entry[K]
case class IntEntry(key: Int) extends Entry[Int]

// Factory stuff:
trait EntryFactory[K] {
  def create(key: K): Entry[K]
}

object EntryFactory {
  implicit def anyFactory[K]: EntryFactory[K] =
    new EntryFactory[K] {
      override def create(key: K) = KEntry(key, key.hashCode)
    }

  implicit object IntFactory extends EntryFactory[Int] {
    override def create(key: Int) = IntEntry(key)
  }

  def create[K: EntryFactory](key: K): Entry[K] =
    implicitly[EntryFactory[K]].create(key)
}


// Works fine when called directly - e1 is KEntry and e2 is IntEntry.
val e1 = EntryFactory.create("Hey")
val e2 = EntryFactory.create(42)
println(e1.toString + ": " + e1.getClass.getName + ";" + e2.toString + ": " + e2.getClass.getName)

// Fails here!!! Why is it KEntry and not IntEntry?
val m = SMap.empty[Int] + 35
println(m.toString + ": " +  m.getClass.getName)
```

Comment: Well, you need to require the typeclass instance either in the `updated` method or at the `trait` level.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Adding it to trait does not help.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez OK, adding the `implicit e: EntryFactory[K]` to all related methods helps. But it means that the generic user code should also add this evidence... which is not feasible.  Say I am adding `def clientMethodGeneric[K](key: K) = SMap.empty + key`. This won't specialize.

Comment: You can ask it at the creation of the `Map` by using an `abstract class` instead of a `trait` - Or, you may consider if a **Typeclass** is not the right approach.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez If you mean like this `abstract class SMap[K](implicit ev: EntryFactory[K])` then it does not work.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Regarding avoiding type-class, what are the options?
I would've consider using something like this, but was trying to avoid the cast of condition:  `def createEntry[K](key: K): Entry[K] = key match { case k: Int => IntEntry(k).asInstanceOf[Entry[K]]; case _  => KEntry(key, key.hashCode) }`